# Run multiples queries in single statement under java

Tags: java, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I would like to select sqlquery from SQLColumn in table1 & then execute the sqlquery in java. However, the query column from table1 contain multiple queries which separated by semicolon.

```
Table1
Name         SQLColumn
-------      ------------------------------------
Query1       set nocount on;select * from table2;
Query2       declare item nvarchar(10); select item=data from table2;

Connection conn = ....
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQLColumn);
ps.execute();
```

Any solution on how to run multiple queries in single statement under java other than stored procedure since the normal preparedstatement only support single query per execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run two separate statements, but inside a single *transaction*, set to whatever isolation level you want.  This would be one way to go here, keeping both statements atomic, meaning that either both complete without error, or else everything would be rolled back.

You commented:

> since the normal preparedstatement only support single query per execution?

This may be the case for SQL Server, but some databases actually expose JDBC driver interfaces which do support multiple statements within a single JDBC call.  However, this is not considered best practice, as it might expose a security hole of some kind.  The transaction suggestion above is a better way to go.